# how to make div to fill remaining space?

Tags: html, css, space, fill

I have very big problem.I have three divs, two divs is of constant width, one is on the left side and other on the right side and i want the third div to occupy remaining space in the middle!
my code is not working!

Thank you in advance.

Html code

```
<div class="center">
<div class="qwert" id="abc1"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<div class="qwert" id="abc2"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<div class="qwert" id="abc3"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Css code

```
#abc1{
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}
#abc3{
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
}
#abc2{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
#abc2{
    width: calc(100% - 450px);
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc): in order to compute the width dynamically.

```css
#abc1{
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}
#abc3{
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
}
#abc2{
    width: calc(100% - 450px);
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
    <div class="qwert" id="abc1"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
        adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="qwert" id="abc2"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
        adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    </div>
    <div class="qwert" id="abc3"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
        adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks man! it worked

Comment: could you explain cal() in css?

Comment: @rahulKushwaha  calc(100% - 450px) means: compute the 100% of the width minus the width of your other two divs (200px + 200px) minus an extra of 50px. I hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

```
*<div style="width:100%">
<div style="width:30%"> <p></p> </div>
<div style="width:40%"> <p></p> </div>
<div style="width:30%"> <p></p> </div>
</div>*
```

this is an example FY easy understanding